# About non-measurable set

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If there is any non-measurable set $X$, then do we say that it is non-measurable with respect to a particular measure or is it non-measurable in general?

For e.g., we clearly have examples of non-measurable sets on real line. Which means that if $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{A})$ is a measurable space then a non-measurable set $X$(say) will not belong to $\mathcal{A}$. However in my Probability Theory class, prof gave us an example of counting measure that is defined on $(\mathbb{R}, 2^{\mathbb{R}})$ where $2^{\mathbb{R}}$ is the power set of $\mathbb{R}$. Now since a power set is the collection of all subsets of the underlying set, it will contain the set $X$ too, which suggests that $X$ is  non-measurable with respect to a some given measure. However, I am not quite sure what actually is the case.

This is my first introduction to Measure theory and that too as a part of the Probability Theory course, so it will be of help if the answer can be put in simple words.

Comment: It is not measurable respect to the measure and the $\sigma$-algebra you take

Comment: Somewhat confusingly, the measure really has little to do with the measurability of sets. All what matters is the *sigma-algebra*, or alternatively the measurable space you're working in. You could definitely define two different sigma-algebras on one set, leading to some sets being measurable in the one while not being measurable in the other.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof Thank you for the reply. I got your point. But could it also be possible that for the same sigma-algebra on one set, a set is measurable with respect to some measure and non-measurable with respect to other?
I mean what exactly is the definition of a measurable set?

Comment: No, by definition. The same $\sigma$-algebra means the same measurable sets.

Comment: Let $m$ denote Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R.$ Let $A\subset \Bbb R$ where $A$ is not Lebesgue-measurable and $|A|=|\Bbb R|=2^{\aleph_0}. $ Let $f:\Bbb R\to A$ be a bijection. Now  for any $B\subset A$ such that $f^{-1}B$ is Lebesgue-measurable, let $m_A(B)=m(f^{-1}B).$ Let $m_A(C)=0$ if $C\subset \Bbb R$ with $C$ disjoint from $ A.$ Observe that $A$ is $m_A$-measurable but not $m$-measurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set-up is that we have a set $(X,\mathcal{A})$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ (a measurable space, analogous to a topological space). Subsets of $X$ that are in $\mathcal{A}$ are called measurable (like open in topology), subsets that are *not* in $\mathcal{A}$ are non-measurable (we could call those sets non-open in a topology, though this is not a usually considered thing).

So in the case of the power set *all* subsets are measurable by definition. And all functions on it are measurable too. Not very interesting. In many practical cases we both have a topology and a $\sigma$-algebra on a set and often related (Borel sets, Baire sets, etc.) Then it gets more interesting IMHO..

If you add the function $\mu: \mathcal{A} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ obeying the right axioms, we say we have a "measure space" (not merely measurable, but we then have fixed/chosen a measure on it too). Then we can talk about sets that have a finite measure, or are measurable for the outer measure etc. (see later in a course on real analysis).

So it's not the *measure* that tells us if a set is measurable but the $\sigma$-algebra on which it is defined.

Comment: So this is what I have understood, if a measure $\mu$ cannot be defined for some set $A$ without leading to any contradictions, then $A$ cannot belong to any $\sigma$-algebra for which $\mu$ can be defined. Am I right in saying this?
If yes, doesn't it shows that the measurability of $A$ depends on $\mu$?

Comment: @SanketAgrawal that understanding is not quite correct.

Comment: Could you please explain where I am wrong?
Should I say instead that $\mu$ cannot be defined on any $\sigma$-algebra that contains the set $A$? @HennoBrandsma

Comment: @SanketAgrawal sometimes you can prove that given $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mu$, we cannot extend $\mu$ to a set $A \notin \mathcal{A}$. But then $A$ could very well be measurable in another $\sigma$-algebra on that set (and another $\mu$).

Comment: Alright, I see your point. Maybe I will understand it better as I go further in the course. But Thank you @HennoBrandsma